# Is Corona SDK fast enough for a Dwarf Fortress like game?

Tags: enums, lua, coronasdk

I want to make a dwarf fortress like game. Would the Corona SDK be fast enough? How would I store the data for each individual block. Since I can't make an enum in Lua, how would I define the type of block?

Comment: If you don't know how to store information in Lua I suggest you learn  the very basics of Lua befor you attempt to program an entire game. if Corona is fast enough would depend on the machien you're running it on. Just search the web for games made with Corona and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you make an enum in Lua? Just use a simple table.

```
brickType = { A = 1,
              B = 2,
              C = 3,
}

myFristBrick = { weight = 500,
                 volume = 50,
                 type = brickType.C
}
```

You can model very complex data structures using Lua tables. So storing your brick data is the least concern you should have.

Answer (score 0):

I use this with meta tables, to simulate enumTypes

```
local enumType_MT = {
    __newindex = function (t, k, v)
        if t [k] then
            print ('redeclaring enum type ' .. k .. ' not permited')
        else
            rawset (t, k, {})
            local c
            for c = 1, #v do
              rawset (t [k], v[c], c)
              rawset (t[k], c, v[c])
            end
         end
    end
}

local myEnumTypes = {}
setmetatable( myEnumTypes, enumType_MT )

myEnumTypes ['foo']  = {'brick_A', 'brick_B', 'brick_C'}
myEnumTypes ['doo']  = {'brick_E', 'brick_F', 'brick_G'}

myVar = myEnumTypes['foo'].brick_A
print (myVar) -- outputs 1
myVar = myEnumTypes['foo']['brick_C']
print (myVar) -- outputs 3
myVar = myEnumTypes['foo'][2]
print (myVar) -- outputs 'brick_B'

myVar = myEnumTypes['doo'].brick_A
print (myVar) -- outputs nil as brick_A not in doo
myVar = myEnumTypes['doo']['brick_C']
print (myVar) -- outputs nil as brick_C not in doo
myVar = myEnumTypes['doo'][2]
print (myVar) -- outputs 'brick_F'
```